# Laravel API Server 500 error while hosting

Tags: laravel, vue.js, heroku

I have developed a website using laravel API and Vuejs. My website works fine on `localhost` but when I upload it on hostinger or heroku it's giving me `500 error` on some of the routes.

Error Image:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried cleaning caches, views? Try `php artisan optimize`

Comment: Yeah not working

Comment: [HTTP 500](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_Error) is a generic server-side error message. On its own it doesn't tell us anything useful. Any time you see this your first step should be to check your error logs for more detail, e.g. by running `heroku logs`.

Comment: Can you check the response of the 500 error?